# How to do dynamic URL Rewriting in J2EE

Tags: java, url, jakarta-ee, url-rewriting

Back in my ASP.NET days, I used [URLRewriter.NET](http://urlrewriter.net/) to do dynamic URL Rewrites.  Basically, it's an HTTPModule that intercepts page requests and rewrites the URLs according to rules that you define, very similar to MOD_REWRITE.  However, it also lets you define a "Custom Transform," a class with a single method that does URL translations for you on-the-fly.  You can have this method hit the DB, access the Application[] collection, pretty much do anything your heart desires.

Is there any equivalent to this in the J2EE world?  I want to be able to rewrite URLs dynamically and delegate this rewriting to some Java code.  I do NOT want to just set up a list of static rewrites.  Likewise, it needs to do actual URL masking, and NOT 3XX redirects.

If there isn't anything out there that does this, how would I go about building this functionality myself?

Comment: Thanks to all for pointing me in the right direction!  It's looking like this may be easy to do after all.  From what I can tell, RequestDispatcher.Forward() will do pretty much exactly what I want.  Do anybody know of any downsides or "gotchas" associated with this approach?

Comment: Don't know your exact problem domain, but that sounds very doable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you investigated [Servlet Filters](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/Filters.html)?  I have not attempted to modify the URL directly and I believe the parameters would be pre-parsed into the request object, but we use the filters extensively for parsing URLs and putting path info into the DB for other Servlet and JSP use.

You could very easily wrap the request object as it chains through to the target Servlets.

Comment: +1: filters is the way to go. Use `HttpServletRequest#getRequestURI()` to parse the pathinfo.

Comment: In fact, there are a few open-source URL-rewrite filters already available, such as OCPsoft Rewrite and PrettyFaces.

http://ocpsoft.com/rewrite/
or
http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/

Answer (score 4):

How about these:

http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/

> PrettyFaces is an OpenSource Filter-based Servlets extension with
>   enhanced support for JavaServer Faces – JSF 1.1, 1.2 and 2.0 –
>   enabling creation of bookmark-able, pretty URLs. PrettyFaces solves
>   the “RESTful URL” problem elegantly, including features such as:
>   page-load actions, seamless integration with faces navigation, dynamic
>   view-id assignment, managed parameter parsing, and configuration-free
>   compatibility with other web frameworks.

http://ocpsoft.com/rewrite/

> Rewrite is an OpenSource Filter-based Servlets extension for Java –
>   enabling creation of bookmark-able, pretty URLs. Rewrite solves the
>   “RESTful URL” problem elegantly, including features such as: page-load
>   actions, managed parameter parsing, seamless integration with CDI,
>   Spring, and configuration-free compatibility with other web
>   frameworks.

http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

> Based on the popular and very useful
>   mod_rewrite for apache,
>   UrlRewriteFilter is a Java Web Filter
>   for any J2EE compliant web application
>   server (such as Resin, Orion or
>   Tomcat), which allows you to rewrite
>   URLs before they get to your code. It
>   is a very powerful tool just like
>   Apache's mod_rewrite.

Comment: It's a powerful tool and we use it on a lot of projects, but it relies on a hard coded list of rules in an XML document.  It's definitely the way to go if you don't need to make it up on the fly.

Comment: We use it too, because of history, but it's increasingly frustrating to use, in particular because the rules don't chain.  Only one gets to match.

Comment: OCPsoft Rewrite doesn't suffer that same limitation of Tuckey.

Answer (score -1):

The other option is write your won **Servlet** . Now write some URL manipulation code using the request object and URL found and call the intended page action or Servlet again.

Eg.

you should call Servlet using URL

domain/urlServlet/param1/param2/...

And your Servlet will translate it to

domain/requestedPage?p1=param1&p2=param2...